# How multi key index is done in SOLR

Tags: database, indexing, database-design, solr, nosql

Multikey is a array field in the Collection. It's  easy to index if the field is not an array field.  For an example

```
 {
    {
      "message":"msg1",
      "tags":["abc","cde","efr"]
    },
    {
      "message":"msg2",
      "tags":["abc,"efgh","efk"]
    },
    {
      "message":"msg3",
      "tags":["abc,"efgh","efr"]
    }
  }
```

Here tags are multi-key field and There is a term in Solr called `multiValued=true|false` . I would like to know how the multi-key field is indexed in Solr. Could some one explain in architectural perspective since there is not enough resources in the internet to explain about this.

Comment: So what are you asking? How to configure the field? Or how it's implemented behind the scenes? There really isn't any magic behind the scenes - it's just indexed (at least it was) as separate terms, with a large positional increment between them to avoid them matching positional queries like `"abc efgh"`

Comment: I am asking about how it is implemented. I could not understand your question. Could you please explain more on this ?

Answer (score 0):

When the multiple terms are given for a single field (i.e. when multivalued is true), the tokens are indexed as they would be for any other field, they're just indexed with a large distance between them so they don't affect each other when querying for phrases. In your example above, `"abc"` would have position 0, `"cde"` would have position 100, `"efr"` would have position 200. If they were indexed as a single field (`"abc cde efr"`), they would have position 0, position 1 and position 2.

Since this position gap is so large, querying for `"cde efr"` will not give a hit, as it usually would for tokens indexed after each other. The setting `positionIncrementGap` is used to adjust this value.

> `positionIncrementGap`
>
> For multivalued fields, specifies a distance between multiple values, which prevents spurious phrase matches

Outside of this there is no special handling of multivalued fields when it comes to the actual indexing. Each value / set of tokens are present for the field as they would be if they had been indexed as one value, but their positions are adjusted behind the scenes to keep them from affecting each other.